# DLL load error in debug mode ,but release mode is ok

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7, dllimport

When I use the `VS2008` to build my project, I use my own `DLL`. It works all right in `release` mode, but when I change it to `debug` mode, I get an error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in DDKWidget.exe`

**Additional information**: `Unable to load the DLL "DDKLibA.dll": The specified module could not be found.`

The `DDKWidget` and `DDKLibA.dll` is my project excutable file and my self-created `DLL`.
I created my `DLL` in `C++`,but I use my it in my `C#` project, using `[DllImport("DDKLibA.dll")]`.

My `OS` is `Win7 64 bit`.
My `IDE` is `VS2008 SP1`.

Did anyone encounter this before?
BTW, it was all ok some time ago, but recently, since I re-installed my `OS`, I started getting these errors. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with 64-bit vs 32-bit mismatch. CLR applications by default get compiled for "AnyCPU" which means that they would automatically run as 64-bit processes on a 64-bit OS.

On the other hand, C++ dlls have to be compiled either for 32-bit or 64-bit and once compiled they stay that way.

You can force a C# app to run in 32-bit mode even under 64-bit OS but that setting can be changed independently for Debug and Release configurations.

My guess would be that your C++ dll is compiled as 32-bit and your Debug setting for your C# dll is also 32-bit but in the Release mode it is set to AnyCPU. That way it would runs as 64-bit process and will not be able to load the 32-bit C++ dll.

Comment: it was exactly you said. my dll was build in 32-bit,but when i use depends.exe check my dll ,it got another two errors.Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

Comment: i have solved my problem.
The first thing i want to notice is that ,when using system dlls ,please check is it 32-bit or 64-bit ,they are different.
the second thing is the key to solve my problem is that ,when i put the missing dll to system32 folder ,i have to put a copy to syswow64 folder too!!! that's all my problem to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

where in the filesystem is the dll located? Maybe you copied it to the same directory as your release exe, but forgot to do the same for the debug exe?

Comment: i have solved my problem.
The first thing i want to notice is that ,when using system dlls ,please check is it 32-bit or 64-bit ,they are different.
the second thing is the key to solve my problem is that ,when i put the missing dll to system32 folder ,i have to put a copy to syswow64 folder too!!! that's all my problem to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen this occur is when a dependent DLL is missing. For example, the release version of your assembly is dependent on foo.dll, but the debug version is dependent on foo-debug.dll. If foo-debug.dll is not installed on the target system, the debug version of your assembly can't be loaded.

I suggest you use a file monitoring utility such as [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see which files the OS is attempting to load when your DLL is loaded.

Comment: i uses the  [dependency walker] find that i have missed two modules,but when i download it and put them to system32 folder,the depends got two errors :Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a little bit different.

In the ABC project I have a nuget package that I've created for convenience to include on other projects.

Both the ABC project and the nuget package are built with .NET7 and have the same Debug/Release settings.

I can run all other projects that have the same nuget package installed in Debug/Release mode without any issue, but in the ABC project it's giving an error which couldn't load this assembly **only in debug mode**:

- Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch

The nuget package have the following packages:

- Serilog.AspNetCore
- Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment
- Serilog.Enrichers.GlobalLogContext
- Serilog.Exceptions
- Serilog.Sinks.Async
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki
- Serilog.Sinks.Http
- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Hosting
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog.Formatting.Compact
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Debug
- Serilog.Sinks.File
- And some other from Microsoft... and System... but I guess they are not relevant

So this was driving me crazy, cause as you can see the assembly that couldn't be loaded was not even being used neither in the nuget package and the ABC project.

I had re-checked over and over again for wrong configurations and also tried the solutions above but none had solved the issue.

This is how I fixed the problem: (I'm using Rider 2022.3)

- Deleted bin folder
- Deleted obj folder
- Rider => Tools => Nuget => Nuget Force Restore

After I've done this I re-run the ABC in debug mode and issue was gone.
Hope it helps someone.